# What is causing my Wordpress site to load so slowly?

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

So I recently setup a Wordpress site that is being hosted through HostGator with their business share-hosting plan. The website was experiencing very slow load times, sometimes up to 30-45 seconds.

I went ahead and scaled down/resized all the images that are currently on the site, added a caching plugin (W3 Total Cache), an optimization plugin (WP-Optimize), a CDN (Truespeed CDN), minified js/css, and added expires headers.

The site scores much better on site speed tests after I made these changes
Pingdom: 87
GTmetrix: 92%/87%
and it seems that the timing to the first byte is pretty quick too.

Loading the site in its current state still feels pretty slow and after taking these measures, I'm unsure of what could be causing the issue, or if possibly the host might be too slow. Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

The url for the site is: http://vmklighting.com/
I am also using Shopisle Theme with Woocommerce and WPML.

Comment: I tried your website on GTMetrix and it is showing almost 5s of "waiting request" in Waterfall tab for the domain. That seems too much. I'm guessing the host is too slow.

Comment: googles insights was waiting 4.3 seconds for response from your server

Comment: note - before google is not complaining about this, it should be below 200 ms

Comment: Thanks so much for your input guys. My guess was also that the host was too slow after going through the measures I took. After running the site through Google insights, it did suggest that the server response time was too slow as well. 

Do you think it is directly attributed to the host? Should I try out a VPS or a Wordpress optimized server to see if it does the trick?

Comment: Please check the issues and try to fix one by one.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvmklighting.com%2F

Comment: One of thousand of possibilities: check the traffic using a live-traffic plugin; I use WordFence to see it. Sometimes the `XMLRPC.php` receives tons of requests (kind of DDoS) and that could make the server respond slowly because of the CPU usage.